# asprintf gives me junk

Tags: c, malloc, buffer, overflow

I am writing to a log file regularly, and I have this function:

```
void write_log(char *logmessage)
```

If I can write the log message directly. When I try to pass the value of a member of a struct, I'm getting an error.

```
typedef struct
{
  char *someValue;
} test;

test *example = malloc(sizeof(test));
```

It is assigned a value from a MYSQL ROW

```
example->row[0];
```

But, `asprintf(&logmessage, "%s%s", "The value of test is ", example->someValue);` is giving me junk.

Comment: Check if `asprintf` returns -1 - it would mean there was an error. What type is `xyz`?

Comment: xyz is char as well. I am not getting -1.

Comment: Might help to show the actual code for the `write_log` function.

Comment: void write_log(char *msg)
{
 syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "%s", msg);
}

Comment: I would suggest `#define write_log(...) syslog(LOG_NOTICE, __VA_ARGS__ )`. That way you can call `write_log` in the same way that you would call `printf`.

Comment: "xyz is char as well"  Do you mean "xyz is `char *` as well"?

Comment: Check the `options` values in code's `void openlog(const char *ident, int option, int facility);` call.

Comment: Tried this. Still getting the same output unfortunately. I'm very much confused here.

Comment: It would help if you included a small example of code that exhibits the behaviour you observe. Note that `asprintf()` (see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf)) allocates the string memory for you so you just have to free it after use.

Comment: I've narrowed it down and will edit my post.

Comment: What is assigned to `example->someValue`?